# How to use Restler with Laravel 5.*? I want to use a eloquent in Restler

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1, restler

I have try to integrate a Restler 3 with Laravel 5 using [luracast/restler](https://packagist.org/packages/luracast/restler) but I am stuck how to use Laravel DB and eloquent with Restler. Please help me or give reference links. Thanks.

Give me suggestion for another helpful API.

Answer (score 0):

I've been there before.

Your best bet here would be to use [Ardent](https://github.com/laravel-ardent/ardent), as Eloquent is a hard beast to be tamed outside of Laravel. Ardent [does that work for you](https://github.com/laravel-ardent/ardent#usage-outside-of-laravel-since-11) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use eloquent template from [Restler Application](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler-Application/tree/eloquent). README.md provides information needed to get started.